# What is this succulent plant?

Tags: identification, succulents

[image: unknown sort of succulent]

Hi!  I’m trying to figure out what this plant is  so I can learn how better to nurture and hopefully replicate it.  Thanks!

Comment: It looks like some species of *crassula* - but not the "jade plant" *crassula ovata*, unless it is a very weedy-looking and untypical example. It looks like it isn't getting enough light, which is making the stems grow too long and the "leaves" too widely separated.